# Substring by specific character

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with hundreds of file paths e.g:

```
list <- c("01_MESS/MS List 05-05-2021.pdf" , "02_PS Art/PDF/PS10.pdf", "04_Art/PDF/Plan/Drain PS 13.pdf",  "05_AC/PDF/Detail/PS 54.pdf")
df<- data.frame(list)
```

Now I want to substring at the last forwardslash --> I just need the file name.

What I tried:

```
df %>% mutate(new_col = stringr::str_extract(list, "^.*(?=/)"))
```

How can I set up the code to extract everything after the last forwardslash?

Comment: `basename(df$list)` or `sub('.*/', '', df$list)`

Comment: If you want the filenames the above code should work. Are you looking for something else? What does first backslash refer to?

Comment: Thx, that works fine. but is there way to do it within the loop to keep the dataframe and add an extra colum?

Comment: @marc_s, true my, allready mended it

Comment: `df$filename <- basename(df$list)`